# Getting list of file names in a directory

Tags: r

If I have a directory full of files and subfolders, how would I be able to use R to get all the list of file names and output them as a csv?

For instance in  `C:\Files`, I have `test1`, `test2`, `test3` as subfolders and have `pic1.jpg` as a file. In `test1` subfolder, I further have other files and subfolders.

Currently, my approach is to set each end subfolders as working directory and then listing out all the file names, before converting them to a dataframe. Finally, I combine all the rows into one dataset.

Other than the alternative approach of copy and pasting all files manually into a single folder and then listing the file names, would there be a more efficient way of getting the list of names in the directory?

Comment: `dir(recursive = TRUE)`

Comment: or `list.files(recursive = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following code will help

```
# To list all files of a folder in a list variable including files 
# from sub-folders. The code below gets the full path of files not just names.
list = list.files(path = full_path_to_directory ,full.names=TRUE,recursive=TRUE)
# To get names of all files from their corresponding paths in all_names variable.
all_names = basename(list)
# To write all_names variable to a CSV file.
write.csv(all_names, "test.csv")
```